# A question about fundamental lemma of calculus of variations

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

The fundamental lemma of calculus of variations tells us,

suppose $f\in L_{loc}^1\Omega\;$  and
$$\int_\Omega f\varphi=0,\forall\varphi\in C^\infty_0\Omega$$
Then $f=0\text{ a.e.}$

My question is again suppose that $f\in L_{loc}^1\Omega\;$ but this time
$$\int_\Omega fD^i\varphi=0,\forall\varphi\in C^\infty_0\Omega,and  \; for\;all \;i$$
do we have $f=C\text{ a.e.}$?

This question is related to [A variant of the fundamental lemma of calculus of variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/32959/aden-dong), but in there the background is set in distributions, which I'm not familiar.

Comment: Your condition means that $f$ has weak derivatives equal to $0$, from which we can conclude $f$ is a.e. constant.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to prove this so that I could say if f has weak derivatives equal to 0, then we can conclude f is a.e. constant. (I know there are other ways to prove this statement, I just wonder if I could prove it this way). Is it possible to prove this directly? Like you prove the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations.

Comment: Yes, this is true. It is surprisingly difficult to prove. It does not follow directly from the fundamental lemma.